# Can't compile C in Devc++

Tags: c, dev-c++

I have tried running a simple piece of C code in DevC++.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> 

int main()
{
int a,b;
printf("Temporary secretary"); 
return 0;
}
```

Every time i try to compile it, it makes "makefile.win" and points out an error on line 25.

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T1vlb.png)

Comment: You have both `main.c` and `Untitled.c` both of which have `main` defined. Delete on or the other.

Comment: You are compiling two files, main.c and Untitled2.c, which of these files are shown here?

Comment: is `gcc` on the `PATH` as seen by the IDE?

Comment: You tagged this post [C++] but state it is a C program.

Comment: Makefiles use *semantically significant* whitespace, and distinguishes been semantically significant **tab** indentation versus semantically significant **space** indentation.  Are you using the appropriate whitespace?

Comment: https://idownvotedbecau.se/beingunresponsive

Answer (score 0):

The error message in the build window is telling you exactly what the problem is - you have multiple definitions of `main`, one in `main.c` and the other in `Untitled2.c`.

Based on what you have posted, it's not clear why `Untitled2.c` is part of the  build - I would remove it from the project completely.

In the future, please do not post links to images of screenshots - copy and paste any code (which includes makefiles) and error messages into the body of your question.  We can't copy and paste from a screenshot, and chasing random links is unsafe.